Computer wont fully shutdown when WOL is enabled
I recently tried installing Linux on my system again. I first tried POP_OS. Where I originally encountered the problem, that although the OS would shutdown, the fans would keep spinning and my GPUs LEDs kept blinking.
I suspected the OS. So I switched to kubuntu, but the problem persists.
Then I read that disabling Wake On Lan in BIOS could Fix the Problem. AND IT DID!
My Problem is I want to use WOL to remotely power on my system. But then my PC won't turn off :(
(Powering the PC on with WOL works, I also checked my systemctl logs and the pc seems to reach poweroff.target)
Thanks in advance!
System: AMD 7600, RX 6800, Asrock B650M Motherboard

Your question starts being off-topic (Pop OS is Ubuntu based, but isn't a Ubuntu product), then you do mention an on-topic product (Kubuntu) but give no clues as to what release you're using, or other details (kernel stack for example if available; LTS releases have choice), so our ability to help is limited; even if your question is on-topic (which it often isn't)
